# How do teleprompters work at award ceremonies?

Tags: awards, teleprompter

In award ceremonies, there are often long comedy monologues and I wonder, do the hosts memorize them or is there a teleprompter somewhere? I never see a teleprompter. Is it a gigantic screen up in the gallery or something?

Comment: I've seen announcers mis-pronounce words, so it's pretty clear they're reading them off a teleprompter.  As for the comedy monologues, they're usually reserved for comedians who make a career off memorizing lengthy monologues.  It's probable that due to the "one-off" nature of the event, they might possibly be prompted words or phrases that remind them of the routine or punchlines off the teleprompter, and they ad-lib some of the rest.

Answer (score 4):

[This Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Where-are-the-teleprompters-on-the-Oscars-that-the-presenters-are-reading-from-as-you-don-t-see-them-when-they-show-a-wide-shot-of-the-stage/answer/Robert-Frost-1) provides a visual:

> They are in behind the first section of the audience, as shown in this screen capture taken while Barbra Streisand was introducing BlacKkKlansman.

[image]

However, there may also be [smaller (and mobile) teleprompters](https://prompterpeople.com/blog/prompter-people-at-the-oscars/) in use:

> when the technical staff from the Academy Awards called us a few days before the Oscars we got to work making a custom prompter for their spec:  **it had to fit through a 12" wide gap at the front of the stage and be robust enough to travel on a track beneath the stage and be lowered up and down for the talent.**  The result was **a small rugged prompter with 10x10" glass based on our QPRO series teleprompters**.  You can see the little guy with Sony box camera and Fuji lens attached at the front of the stage.  Many shots were done through our US made low-iron 65-35 glass, it looked great and met the specs required for this world-wide broadcast.

[image]